# Receive events when new windows open in Windows OS using Java with JNA

Tags: java, windows, winapi, events, jna

I am trying to get some sort of notification or event when a new window is opened in Windows OS using Java with JNA.  This is different from JNA's FileMonitor.FileEvent which will notify me of changes in the filesystem (i.e. when a new file is added to a directory etc.).

My goal has to do with when an actual window is opened.  Is there a way to get an event of when a new window is opened (i.e. a new window handle) as opposed to polling periodically with EnumWindows to see when a new handle is returned?

I realize there may be a workaround for this using FileMonitor.FileEvent (perhaps a way to tell when a file is opened in a window?), but I have not discovered it yet.

Comment: I don't know about the JNA part, but you'll likely need to use either the Win32 APIs [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), perhaps with CBT hook, or [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) for EVENT_OBECT_CREATE/SHOW events (and filter for top-level HWNDs). The latter of these has the advantage that it can be used without requiring a separate DLL (use WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT flag), wheras the former requires a separate C++ dll.

Comment: thank you for the tips, I will look into these.

Comment: Kevin, did you ever get it to work? Would you like to post the code so as to help future generations of developers?